# iOS 8 prepare for segue Casting object. Gives Error

Tags: casting, uikit, swift, ios8

So my code below shows me how I am doing prepare for segue. I'm not sure whats going on but its giving me some weird error I've used this same way before and it works but it just won't work in this application.

Code

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if segue.identifier == "select"
    {
        println("helloworld")
        var index = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell!)
        var object = self.objects[index!.row] as HMAccessory // object is a NSmutableArray its crashing on this next line where im casting it
        //var dest = segue!.destinationViewController? as CharacristicsViewController!
       // dest.detailItem = object
    }
}
```

can anybody see anything wrong with this?

This is the error I'm getting.

> **HomeKit`HomeKit.AccessoryTableViewController.prepareForSegue
>   (HomeKit.AccessoryTableViewController)(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional,
>   sender : Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> () at
>   AccessoryTableViewController.swift:23:**

Comment: That's only half the error (the location), what's the rest of it?

Comment: try to unwrap the offending line to restrict the problem source

Comment: So i figured it out , i had not set the views custom class in the story board to the write one as i wrote a new class and was discarding the old class. Thanks for replies though . but yeah these errors never help the rest of the error was just assembly code and i was most def not gonna look through that lol